# What word is best used to describe something that is a reality for you but not a universal fact?

Tags: single-word-requests

I considered the word "circumstantial" or phrase "circumstantially true" but I feel like there's another word that better describes this.

In an example; if you step in a puddle and your feet get wet then that is the truth in your case, but it is not the case that anyone who steps in a puddle will get their feet wet.

Comment: Anyone wearing shoes when they step in a puddle will get said shoes wet. That’s a universal truth.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Unless it's a puddle of a non-wetting liquid. Or the person is barefoot. // It's easier just to edit the example.

Answer (score 2):

This was your **experience**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experience) has:

> **experience**
> <sub>noun</sub>
>
> 3: something personally encountered, undergone, or lived through
> 4a: the conscious events that make up an individual life
> 4b: the events that make up the conscious past of a community or nation or humankind generally
> 5: the act or process of directly perceiving events or reality

Answer (score 0):

It seems credence **[mental acceptance as true or real]** can be a potential answer.

> The performance against Cincinnati adds credence to the belief before SMU’s pivotal game at Tulsa on Saturday.

Meaning and example from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credence).

Answer (score -1):

It's a **subjective** truth or experience.

The word has lots of meanings, but the relevant ones are in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subjective)

> 4a(1) : peculiar to a particular individual
>
> > subjective judgments

> (2): modified or affected by personal views, experience, or background
>
> > a subjective account of the incident